# PostForEntity: 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, media-type

In our project, we call an external API with postForEntity and receive the following: **error:org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException: 415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE "Could not determine reason or message. Plain body: ""**

```
final ActionDto actionDto = new ActionDto ().setRequestId(requestId);
final ResponseEntity<ActionResponseDto> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, actionDto, ActionResponseDto.class);
```

I managed to fix this error by using exchange instead of postForEntity and adding a media type:

```
final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
val entity = new HttpEntity(actionDto , headers);
final ResponseEntity<ActionResponseDto> response =
        restTemplate.exchange(
                url,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                entity,
                ActionResponseDto.class);
```

My question is the following, could you give me some hints why before with postForEntity it worked and now suddenly it doesn't?
I also checked the external API and the method looks like bellow, and nothing has changed:

```
@PostMapping("/action/start")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@Operation(summary = "Start the action")
public ResponseEntity<ActionResponseDto> startAction(@RequestBody final ActionDto requestDto) {
    .....
}
```

Could it be due to some dependencies? This error is very strange...
Thank you! :)

Comment: I'm confused: you say you fixed it by using exchange instead of postForEntity, then you ask why it worked with postForEntity and now doesn't?

Comment: Hi @tgdavies. Yep, because this error appears in several places in the project and I was wondering why it doesn't work all of a sudden.

Comment: "Could it be due to some dependencies?" ..only if you changed(upgrade?) them!;)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion

Comment: postForEntity second parameter is HTTP entity, but you have given pojo class object.